How could $\delta(s, u)$ be equal to the BFS distance $u.d$ in bfs search correctness proof?
I'm studying Breadth-First Search (BFS) from the CLRS book and I'm having trouble understanding the proof that each distance from the source node calculated by BFS is the shortest distance from the source node.
The book presents three lemmas to prove this:
Lemma 1:
For any edge $(u, v) \in E$ in a graph $G = (V, E)$, the shortest distance from the source node $s$ to node $v$ is bounded by:
$δ(s,v)≤δ(s,u)+1$
Lemma 2:
The distance calculated by BFS from the source node $s$ to node $v$ is an upper bound on the shortest distance:
v.d≥δ(s,v)
Lemma 3:
During the execution of BFS, the queue contains nodes in the order $<v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r>$, and the following properties hold:


.

≤

1
.

+
1
and


.

≤


+
1
.

Proof by Contradiction:
Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $v.d > \delta(s, v)$. Then, there exists a node $u$ preceding $v$ in the shortest path from $s$ to $v$. The book asserts that $\delta(s, u) = u.d$. My question is: how can we be sure that the shortest distance $\delta(s, u)$ is equal to the BFS distance $u.d$?

First of all start from definition of distance. Distance between two vertices is length of the shortest path between these vertices. Therefore phrase "shortest distance" means "shortest length of the shortest path", that is non-sense. And it definitely doesn't come from CLRS.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/167957/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4912273/14578.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Note that, according to the proof text, $v$ is not an arbitrary vertex such that $v.d > \delta(s, v)$, but a vertex with minimum $\delta(s, x)$ among all vertices with wrong label $x.d$. Therefore vertex $u$ preceding $v$ in the shortest $(s, v)$-path definitely exists and has correct label $u.d$, because $\delta(s, u) < \delta(s, v)$.
